# Jquery removing element from html

Tags: jquery, dom, html-table

I have this html `var content = $("#directions-panel > .adp").find("div[jsinstance='"+i+"']").prop('outerHTML');`

i'm attempting to remove a first table column within the html.

Here is my attempt but not working.

```
content.findr(".adp-directions > tbody > tr > td.adp-substep:eq(0)").remove();
```

Comment: Try `$(content).find().remove();` (wrap `content` with jQuery's selector).

Comment: Please put sample HTML it will help people to give you working and more accurate code.

Comment: put html code or create jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only remove your first cell with class `adp-substep`.
Instead of what you are doing, try:

```
content.find(".adp-directions > tbody > tr").each(function(){
  jQuery(this).find("> td.adp-substep:eq(0)").detach(); //or remove
});
```

The code above will remove the first cell of each table row.